# Python 3 - '_csv.Error: line contains NULL' error byte when reading csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file that contains NUL
with csv reader
I search a lot for a way to read the file without an error and couldn't find one.

Edit:
Adding the relevant section of the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rtF3ck6QymtH4_n4iUjavPnxZiryq_Q4

My code:

```
   with codecs.open(log_path, 'r') as csv_file:
        log_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for line in log_reader:
            if line['Addition Information'] == str 
               # do something
```

Will appreciate any help
Thanks,
Avishay

Comment: Can you post your CSV?

Comment: I added a link to the relevant section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) (and therefore also [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)) simply can't deal with files containing null bytes.

A possible solution would be to replace null bytes when reading the input file, e.g. by using a generator expression, since `reader()` takes any object supporting the iterator protocol as argument:

```
with codecs.open(log_path, 'r') as csv_file:
    log_reader = csv.DictReader((l.replace('\0', '') for l in csv_file))
    for line in log_reader:
        if line['Addition Information'] == str 
           # do something
```

Comment: Working great!
It's a little bit slower now but it's done the trick
Thanks very much!

Comment: this has worked for me too.Thanks and yes looks bit slow. but fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
with codecs.open(log_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='backslashreplace') as csv_file:
        log_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for line in log_reader:
            if line['Addition Information'] == str 
               # do something
```